# WebDAV testing with Tsung

Tags: webdav, stress-testing, tsung

I have installed Tsung and its up and running for HTTP, however, the main intention is to use Tsung for WebDAV testing. But I do not see recorder picking up any of my actions on a mounted drive. I am using this command:

```
tsung-recorder -p webdav start
```

If I go through browser, then the actions are recorded but if I go via mounted web drive, nothing gets recorded.

I am wondering whether the mounted drive testing for web drive is actually supported by Tsung or not. Also is it possible to perform actions like cretaing, copying, editing resources on mounted drive?

I am also ok to work without recorder (through scripting only) if possible.